# Name for a tool to customize a product online

Tags: terminology

On ecommerce websites (and some others), sometimes there is a tool that shows an image of the product which uses a system of drop downs or check boxes to specify characteristics to customize the product and have the image update to match.

An example of this is [changing colors of a hoodie](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005CSOZ92), but there are many uses

What is this tool called? All that I can think of is "product customizer" or something along those lines.

Comment: A Power search?

Comment: @TylerH It's not a search, it's more of a customizer

Comment: Ahh, like "building your own car" on the website?

Comment: @TylerH It could be used for that, sure

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge-based_configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sales of technical products that have many different configurations the customer may want to change, they use a software tool called a '*product configurator*'.  Although it may sound awkward and it's language correctness is dubious, it has become ubiquitous in the last 25 years.